# Scala: string pattern matching and splitting

Tags: regex, string, scala

I am new to Scala and want to create a function to split `Hello123` or `Hello 123` into two strings as follows:

```
val string1 = 123
val string2 = Hello
```

What is the best way to do it, I have attempted to use regex matching `\\d` and `\\D` but I am not sure how to write the function fully.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may replace with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*+`) that are preceded with letters and followed with digits:

```
var str = "Hello123"
val res = str.split("(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\s*+(?=\\d)")
println(res.deep.mkString(", "))  // => Hello, 123
```

See the [online Scala demo](http://ideone.com/nP4qvI)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` - a positive lookbehind that only checks (but does not consume the matched text) if there is an ASCII letter before the current position in the string
- `\\s*+` - matches (consumes) zero or more spaces possessively, i.e.
- `(?=\\d)` - this check is performed only once after the whitespaces - if any - were matched, and it requires a digit to appear right after the current position in the string.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, is it possible to know how I can also skip a full stop... for example: `Hello. 123` becomes `string1 = Hello` and `string2 = 123`

Comment: You should make it part of the consuming pattern: `"(?<=[a-zA-Z])[.\\s]*+(?=\\d)"`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given string I assume you have to match a string and a number with any number of spaces in between

here is the regex for that

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*(\\d+)
```

Now create a regex object using `.r`

```
"([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*(\\d+)".r
```

***Scala REPL***

```
scala> val regex = "([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*(\\d+)".r

scala> val regex(a, b) = "hello 123"
a: String = "hello"
b: String = "123"

scala> val regex(a, b) = "hello123"
a: String = "hello"
b: String = "123"
```

---

### **Function to handle pattern matching safely**

pattern match with extractors

```
str match {
  case regex(a, b) => Some(a -> b.toInt) 
  case _ => None 
}
```

Here is the function which does Regex with Pattern matching

```
def matchStr(str: String): Option[(String, Int)] = {
  val regex = "([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*(\\d+)".r
  str match { 
    case regex(a, b) => Some(a -> b.toInt) 
    case _ => None 
  }
}
```

*Scala REPL*

```
scala> def matchStr(str: String): Option[(String, Int)] = {
    val regex = "([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*(\\d+)".r
    str match {
      case regex(a, b) => Some(a -> b.toInt)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
defined function matchStr

scala> matchStr("Hello123")
res41: Option[(String, Int)] = Some(("Hello", 123))

scala> matchStr("Hello 123")
res42: Option[(String, Int)] = Some(("Hello", 123))
```